# Associated Class files with a WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Is there a way to get a list of associated class files used to build a web service, using Eclipse, or other utilities?

The service type is a top down java bean web service

I want to know how the WSDL knows what classes to create. And I'm not sure what files to look at.

Comment: WSDLs don't "use class files". What exactly do you need? You can use a  xml parser to access all elements on a wsdl.

Comment: If you mean the classes that used to build the webservice , you can check them from Build path (by right click on your project)

Comment: Thanks Radi that is what I meant. I'll modify the question.

Comment: Could you provide some more information ? For example what library/technology are you using ?

Comment: Using the option `verbose` and `debug` with the tool  `wsimport` of the JDK you can see the generated Java class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eneded up doing was

1. Open the .WSDL file in WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/
   This allows you to view source, or design view of the WSDL.
2. Then you click on the desired input or output arrow next to the chart in design view. This will oppen the associated XSD file.
3. Within the XSD Files, if I find `<xs:complexType name="classNameWillBeHere">`tags, these are what the generated classes would have been called.
4. From there I do a Navigate/Find Type - using the className from the complex type.
5. The class is returned in the project src folder. (assuming you've already built the web service from the WSDL)